# reading excel files in java

Tags: java, excel

Is there a way to read excel file in java without using any third party library, as I'm working on a project where we can't use any opensource library.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: No, unless you want to duplicate all the work that went into creating those third party libraries. That's ... why they exist.

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, no. You'll have to write something yourself (perhaps check out the source code for Apache POI ?). But I suspect that's a *lot* of work.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

From their web site :

***Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents***

but its an open source library.

I don't know why you can't use open source library, but using a non-open source library will cost, and it will be difficult to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Abu's answer may not honor the letter of the "no libraries" law, but it's correct.

I'd prefer [Andy Khan's JExcel](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/) to Apache POI.  I've had great success with the former and no luck at all with the latter.

Your "no library" requirement is a worthwhile instinct, but it's wrongheaded in this instance.  You don't want to reproduce all that work.

I can think of two reasons why you'd avoid dependencies: 1. So you can cherry pick functionality and 2. [To learn how to invent wheels](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000007.html).  Neither applies here, but they're worth remembering.

Comment: Worthwhile is to keep the third party stuff within reason, to completely go out of your way to not have them is just madness IMO.

Comment: I can think of two reasons why you'd avoid them: 1. So you can cherry pick functionality and 2. To learn how to invent wheels.  Neither applies here, but they're worth remembering.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000007.html